# Qt Creator - same file twice without split

Tags: ide, qt-creator

Is it possible to have multiple instances of the same file without creating a split in Qt Creator, e.g. like what 'Window->New Editor' achieves in Eclipse? After some searching I'm inclined to decide it's impossible, but maybe someone can prove me wrong?

Often I'm all for splits, but sometimes I work on screens small enough that I would rather go through bother of additional click to view a larger area of the code at once.

Comment: I do not understand why you would want to do that in the first place, so I think I am maybe just misunderstanding your question:-) What do you want to archive with having the same file open several times in the same editor?

Comment: @Tobias - sometimes I need to work on screens small enough that split just isn't a good solution. But I still want to be able to see two (sometimes more) parts of the same file at once/nearly at once. Thus would like to have the same file opened twice. I would need to switch between two files to view them, but with shortcuts that's still much better than having to scroll within a single instance.

Comment: So this is basically a navigation problem? Try using Ctrl-K followed by ". method" to jump around in the current file. Or use Ctrl-K "l lineno". You can also use Alt-Left/right to jump to locations visited earlier. Not sure whether this helps, but having the same file show up in the navigation history twice would be rather confusing I think.

Comment: I didn't know about those shortcuts. Not 100% what I wanted, but bringing me closer, thank you. And I agree about same file being there twice being confusing, though maybe a subscript (1), (2), etc would be a solution here.

Comment: I for one will fail to remember that file.cpp(1) is where I look at helper_functionA(...) and file.cpp(2) is someOtherFunction(...). Adding more information like line number (does not really help, does it?) or function currently displayed is most likely just getting too long to display properly.